# Return sizeof based on string input

Tags: c, sizeof

I'm looking for a way have a function in C that accepts, as input, a string defining a particular variable type. The function then returns the `sizeof` result of that input as if the string were evaluated as a type. Consider the example below.

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct my_struct {
    int16_t var1;
    int16_t var2;
    int16_t var3;
} mystruct_t;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    return sizeof(argv[1]); // THIS IS WRONG!!
}
```

The user could then compile this and try calling `./myprogram my_struct_t` where I expect this would return the actual C byte size of `my_struct_t` during runtime, on my machine.

The component of this that I'm unsure about is that obviously this gets the size of the (pointer to the) string stored in `argv[1]`, and not the size of the type defined by the string. How can I make this conversion? Is this even possible?

Comment: This is not something built into the C language.  What is it you really wish to accomplish with this functionality?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons It seems you've answered my question. What I really wish to accomplish is have a program like the above that has numerous data types defined in it and allows me to get the runtime size of these types. I want the runtime sizes of these data types for something external to C and was hoping I could just call into an executable.

Comment: `that obviously this gets the size of the string stored in argv[1]` it returns the size of a pointer not the string.

Comment: ***Is this even possible?*** Probably not what you want. Meaning you can create a program that has some string to size table that contains the size of each structure that you specify that you specifically added to your table. Not sure what the practical usage for such an effort.

Comment: Depending on padding and other factors, the result of `./myprogram my_struct_t` might be 6, 8, 12, 16,  32, 3, 4, etc.

Comment: Goal of "actual size" deserves units, `8-bit bytes, C sized "bytes", bits?

Comment: write a c program on the fly and compile and run it (like automake does )

Comment: @pm100 interesting idea. Then you don't have to have a fixed set of types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do something like this directly in C, as it does not have the concept of reflection.

What you can do however is write a shell script to create a C program that defines the type you give it, compile it, and run it to get the size.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

type=$1

cat > size.c  << EOF
#include <stdio.h>

typedef $type thetype;

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(thetype));
    return 0;
}
EOF

gcc -o size size.c
./size
rm size size.c
```

Sample input/output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./x1.sh int
4
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./x1.sh double
8
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./x1.sh "struct { int a; char b; }"
8
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./x1.sh "struct { int a; char b; double c; }"
16
```

Comment: It probably should also include whatever headers are needed for the other `c` code of the library.

Comment: I like this way due to its portability and simplicity. Should've thought of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with a series of if statements. Add one for each type you want to allow the caller to specify:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct my_struct {
    int16_t var1;
    int16_t var2;
    int16_t var3;
} my_struct_t;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    const char * str;

    if ( argc <= 1 )
        return -1;

    str = argv[1];

    if ( 0 == strcmp( str, "int" ) ) 
        return sizeof( int );

    if ( 0 == strcmp( str, "int16_t" ) ) 
        return sizeof( int16_t );

    if ( 0 == strcmp( str, "struct my_struct" ) ) 
        return sizeof( struct my_struct );

    if ( 0 == strcmp( str, "my_struct_t" ) ) 
        return sizeof( my_struct_t );

    return -1; 
}
```

Comment: This is probably the easiest way. Not sure of the OP thought there would be an automatic way of doing this that did not require you to specify each type that you wanted the size.

Comment: I did hope that there would be an automatic way, but since there seems there isn't, this appears to be the next best solution.

Comment: How would the third `if` statement work? `argv[1]` would only contain `struct`

Comment: @P.W `argv[1]` contains whatever the first argument was, which could contain any sort of whitespace. If you execute it from a shell like `./a.out struct my_struct` then yes the first argument is just `struct`, but if you do `./a.out struct\ my_struct` or `./a.out 'struct my_struct'` then the first argument is `struct my_struct`.